# Android: If/else statement with string.equals, returning visual confirmation

Tags: java, android, compare

I've tried coding a sample of a app that checks the user input (`String 1`) from a `EditText` and compares it to a string (in this case `translation 1`).

After answers and suggestions I've updated my Java code and as far as I can figure out i should be working fine, but i does not. (see debugger edit)

Thanks in advance!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- Page Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PageTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/test_title"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<!-- Input 1 -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text=""
    android:hint="@string/hint_input"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/translation1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PageTitle"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

<!-- Translation 1 -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/translation1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/test"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/input1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PageTitle"
    android:background="@drawable/translation_borders"/>

<!--Check button-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="Check"
    android:text="@string/check_btn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/translation1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/input1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PageTitle" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT: updatet code.**

Java:

```
package com.bnf.Overhooring;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    String right = getString(R.string.right);
    String wrong = getString(R.string.wrong);

    EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
    String string1 = input1.getText().toString();
    String translation1 = "a";

    public void Check(View view) {
        if (string1.equals(translation1)) input1.setText(right);
        else input1.setText(wrong);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: posted debugger results**

I've runned the debugger after updating my code and found out that my app keeps closing on startup. The error in the debugger:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.bnf.overhooring, PID: 471
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bnf.overhooring/com.bnf.overhooring.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2849)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
                  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
                  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
                  at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:476)
                  at com.bnf.overhooring.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Is there an error log? And in contradiction to your question it seems as though you're only printing a msg to your log int he code.

Comment: Question is very confusing, what exactly you want? you want to set text to your `translation1` textview in if else statement, and the add listener to it?? Is that so?

Comment: Also, do not use `System.out.println()` while developing android apps, try using `Log.i()` or some other `Log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few mistakes that I would like to point out:

- Do not use a seperate block `{ }` for `if-else`
- Do not use `System.out.println()` for Android Development, try `Log.i()` or any other `Log` statement.
- As of a visual display, try using `EditText.setText()` or `TextView.setText()` function to show visual output in your case.
- To follow the above point, you first need to initialise the corresponding `View`, like `TextView` or `EditText` by `findViewById()` to use `setText()` or `getText()`.

**Edit:** Since your code should run when the activity gets inflated from the layout, put your code after `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`

I would recommend you to go through the [official developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/) for referrals.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the respons I've updated my code and revised the question based on your answer. Now I can't detect any problems myself but mine app keeps stopping on opening. I've runned the debugger and posted the result in the question. I would be very gratefull if you could take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a visual confirmation on the mobile screen, then you could have your `TextView` or `EditText` show it. You could set text to your `EditText input1` using `setText()`.

eg: `input1.setText("Text");`

```
TextView translation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.translation1); 
translation.setText(input1.getText().toString());
```

You can set `OnClickListener` using:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Your code goes here
   } 
});
```

This takes the value from edittext compares and sets a text based on that in a textview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);

      String String1 = input1.getText().toString();

      String translation1 = "a";

      Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

          if(String1.equals(translation1)) {
              //System.out.print("This right!");
              translation.setText("This right!");
          } else {
              //System.out.print("This is wrong!");
              translation.setText("This wrong!"); 
          }
       } 
   }
}
```